# Redirect user with nginx depending on response from remote php script

Tags: php, nginx, server

I am looking into redesigning the way my home server works with a more secure network and a log in system that will be used to access it's services and manage users. To contact the server, you would first contact a VPS with tinc and nginx. Nginx would contact the server (PHP) and depending on the response direct them to the service, or direct them to a log in page.

I know how I will be doing most of this, besides the Nginx redirect part, I am not even sure if that is doable.

Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you redirect from the PHP script?

```
if($foo) {
    header("Location: https://google.com/$foo"); // redirect to google
}
```

Comment: If I did that, then I would have to make a new php script for ever service I create, which isn't a bad thing, but I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Thinking about it, I am going with this, simple and uncomplicated